# Child element inheriting width issue

Tags: css, margin

So I am having this strange issue where i have an element in a container and it is inheriting the width from the conatiner.

to try and fix this i just set the css width property to whatever i want. when i go to preview in the browser it has adjusted the width properly, but it has now extended out the right margin to fill in the container.

I tried to offset this by doing things like margin-right: 0; or using negative values, but nothing is working

Comment: Can't help you without your code.

Comment: Need to see the codes. Initial guess without seeing codes would be that it is also inheriting margin/padding/border from it's parent and adding those to the width that you are specifying.

Comment: @BillyMoat I guess BOX MODEL is the issue, overflowing paddings and border

Comment: This all sounds totally normal, I have no idea what you want to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width of the child is never inherited from the parent(the exact value specified on the parent)! However, it **is** dependent on the parent's width. If you specify a width on the parent and have a block-level child, it will always expand to 100% of the parents width. That is completely normal behavior.

If you set an explicit width on a child-element, you have to be aware, that it's *padding and border* are not accounted into the total width (using standard box modell). You have two options:

- account the padding
- alter the box-modell

the css:

```
#parent{
   width:100px;
}
#child{
   padding:10px;
   width:100px;   /* child will be 20px too wide */
}
/*method 1*/
#child{
   padding:10px;
   width:80px;   /* child will fit perfectly: 80px +10px + 10px */
}
/* method 2*/
#child{
   padding:10px;
   width:100px;
   box-sizing:border-box;      /* child will fit perfectly
                               width now includes content and padding */
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* for compatibility*/
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

note however, that `box-sizing` is a newer css-property and not every browser can handle it.

Comment: Your answer does not account for the browser window being resized!

Comment: @Reado Box sizing has absolutely nothing to do with the width of the browser window (responsive design). These are two completely separate topics, and also it was not part of the question. This answer is there to clarify the issue of misfitted elements due to the unintuitive box sizing model and how to fix this not to create a responsive design. If you have questions about responsive designs, simply ask a different question, if you think the answer is lacking information, improve (edit) it, but please don't downvote it for a reason that was never part of the question in the first place.